# Add pulse to sinewave (high voltage)

Tags: voltage, ac, power-electronics

I am looking to add a pulse to a sinewawave. The input is high voltage AC so I cant use an op-amp adder. I have also used tried to combine the signals through large resistors but that only averages the signal. It attenuates it by 2. I could amplify the signal by 2 but I would rather not. Is there a straight forward way to impose the pulse on the sinewave, (like in the image below). Its easy to do in LTSpice, not so easy in reality.

Thanks.

Edit 1:

Its part of a 3-phase rectifier which uses IGBT's instead of diodes (added below). I will use a separate circuit to generate the pulses accordingly.

[image]

The circuit and timing works fine. The plot below shows the gate-emitter voltage with the 10V pulse imposed on it. (the sine wave is only 20V in this simulation but will be a higher voltage in reality, these components don't work at higher levels).

[image]

The problem here is adding the pulses to the real-world circuit.

Comment: Your schematic looks invalid with a load and AC on the drain of an inverted NFET and shows no fundamental understanding., nor an input output spec.

Comment: You will need to provide more information about this pulse and what you expect it to look like.  How big is this pulse, and at what point in the cycle do you need it?  Does the pulse have a direction?  Also, your schematic doesn't make sense and provides no information with which to help you.

Comment: I have updated the post so hopefully it is much clearer now. If not do let me know.